# proper use of Vue Watch

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js, event-handling

I want to fire a method only if a certain `data` value equals `true`. after scouring the doc's, I decided to use the `Watch` option, however I just want to check against a `true` value:

```
  export default {
    data () {
        return {
            staticMode: true,
        }
      },
      methods: {
        checkStatic: function() { 
           ...
           console.log('static mode is on')
        }
      },
      watch: {
        staticMode: function () {
          if(this == true) {
            checkStatic()
        }
      }
```

The watch method id never fired as nothing gets logged in the console. I'm sure the syntax is off... any suggestions?

Comment: You need `this` in `this.checkStatic()`. Also, it should be checking `if (this.staticMode === true)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The new value of the watched variable is passed into the function like so:

```
export default {
    data () {
        return {
            staticMode: true,
        }
      },
      methods: {
        checkStatic: function() { 
           ...
           console.log('static mode is on')
        }
      },
      watch: {
        staticMode: function (value) {
          if(value === true) {
            console.log(true)
            this.checkStatic()
        }
      }
}
```